# How to make bash suggest history like zsh without pressing arrow key

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, zsh, autosuggest

I know how to make the [zsh like history completion in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299437/zsh-like-history-in-bash) .
But i need auto suggest feature like zsh(like shown in image)[image]. when i type the letters it suggest the history without even pressing any keys. In this case when i type "do" it suggest the previous history "dolphin". But with or without tab-completion of that command. Can anyone help reproduce this autosuggest feature in bash.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This looks like a better question to be asked in a *nix exchange: perhaps https://askubuntu.com/ (there are many linux/bash/zsh users there). I am interested in the answer though - post a link if you do ask elsewhere :)